# Custom Extension Need to save Input Text and Output It in the Template

Tags: template, configuration

Here is what I have so far. I am not sure how to save the text fields (url's) and insert them into the template. Any help with this would be great :)

**config.xml**

http://pastebin.com/UZfVLs6P

**system.xml**

http://pastebin.com/y5rkKfE0

**adminhtml.xml**

http://pastebin.com/syx88dyZ

**Helper/Data.php**

http://pastebin.com/DqMkc2JA

And the template file. This is where I would like to replace the `#` sign in the url's with the users input if it exists:

```
<?php if (Mage::helper('themesettings')->getCfg('socialaccounts/enable')): ?>

<div id="footerSocial">
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img title="Facebook" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>media/beckin/social/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /> 
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img title="Twitter" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>media/beckin/social/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /> 
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img title="Youtube" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>media/beckin/social/youtube.png" alt="Youtube" /> 
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img title="Google" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>media/beckin/social/google.png" alt="Google" /> 
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img title="Flickr" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>media/beckin/social/flickr.png" alt="Flickr" /> 
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img title="Linkedin" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>media/beckin/social/linkedin.png" alt="Linkedin" />
</a>
</div>

<div class="breaker"></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it :)

I just needed to add this to the template.

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('themesettings/socialaccounts/facebook') ?>
```